# Can I extend an otherwise wireless network to a wired-only computer through a second wireless router?

Tags: local-area-network, wlan

[This](https://serverfault.com/questions/41572/adding-a-second-wireless-router-to-my-network) question is incredibly similar, but DIFFERENT. so before you vtc, please hear me out.

I have my wireless router [**router1**] connected to my ISP.
I have a wireless network being broadcast from **router1** through my house.
I have a computer in my living room [**failbox**] that does NOT have wireless connectivity.
I want to use a SECOND wireless router [**router2**], to 'catch' the network broadcasted by **router1**.
**Router2** will then (hopefully) extend the network *BY WIRE* to **failbox**

how can I do this?

[Edit - To clarify any questions, the distance is too great for me to connect the routers by wire. The two routers have to be able to communicate with each-other by wireless only]

Comment: why downvotes? help me out here people .if the question has been answered or is easily solvable point me in the right direction. I'm extremely uneducated in the category of networking.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Home networking questions are off topic for serverfault. It may be on topic for Superuser but check their [faq](http://superuser.com/faq) and search their site before asking.

Comment: @Lain i read the faq. i fail to see how this is offtopic

Comment: This is actually quite a bit off-topic, because looks a lot more like a home/user question, while this site is dedicated to professional system/network administration.

Comment: You're administering a computer in your living room named failbox in a **professional capacity**?

Comment: @Lain ok... it doesnt say that in your faq. just saying.

Comment: `"And it is not about... **Anything in a home setting**"`

Comment: @Ender: It clearly says And it is not about **Anything in a home setting**

Comment: @MDMarra I just used whatever term came to mind. Now your just nitpicking. Regardless of what the FAQ says, if I was unaware home problems were offtopic here I would'nt have posted the question. Sorry and thanks for the explanation. Ill try superuser. :D

Comment: @Lain ZOMG FAIL ME! D: How did I miss that? Hundred apologies.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's called a wireless bridge. Get an AP that supports being in bridged mode.

Also, this is off-topic. Take a minute to read the FAQ for the site that you are on before you post in the future.

Answer (score 0):

What you would need is a so-called "ad-hoc" wireless configuration, where two devices talk between themselves without a central access point to bind to; many wireless adapters support this, as this is typically used when you *don't* have an access point; some routers/APs support it too, so you maybe *can* configure the two routers to participate in the same wirelss network; but this strongly depends on those routers' features and configuration.

Also, if one of the routers can be configured as a wireless *client*, instead of acting as an access point, you could have it connect to the other one's network and achieve the same result. Again, whether this is actually doable depends on the specific routers we are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what wifi capabilities router2 has. If it can be turned into a wireless bridge, its possible, but most don't support this feature.